# post data with yahoo pipes

Tags: html, http-post, yahoo-pipes, mashup

I'd like to include a Wordle ([wordle.net)](http://www.wordle.net) in my mashup. But wordles require the data to be sent over via post: [wordle.net/advanced](http://www.wordle.net/advanced).

Is there any way to send data via POST using Yahoo Pipes?

Comment: Yeah well... Got the tumbleweed badge for that one. I think I ought to repost a better thought out version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution at last... Though I'm not sure pipes and I are friends any more.

The pipe: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=de24ea125f4fe90d9394d15c5c03e776

The twitter search is straightforward, then using regex the tweets are concatenated into one long string.

The string has a form tag appended - open before the data, then with the submit and close after.

[image: The regex is built up using a string builder.]

The result is placed into the title of the single item returned, so that the RSS' title contains the form we want to display. The end-user has to submit the form manually but with a little javascript and CSS sugar-coating that can be arranged.

It's not a very good use of pipes though - in the end, pipes can very nicely do the search and arguably the concat. Then that should be consumed by another process that can produce a better looking form, or even better, directly show the wordle by loading the Java Applet.